# What does the ending `+x` mean in this bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, parameter-expansion

What does the ending `+x` mean in the `BUILD_ENV_IMAGE+x` of below script?

```
if [[ -z "${BUILD_ENV_IMAGE+x}" ]]; then
    BUILD_ENV_IMAGE="${CI_CONTAINERS_REGISTRY}/build-env:${CI_CONTAINERS_BASE_TAG}-gcc11"
fi
```

I am not sure if it is bash or sh specific. So I add both tags.

### ADD 1 -- 2:10 PM 1/14/2023

A sample

```
# var is set to null
var=


# check if var is unset or null
echo ${var:+literal_out_put} abc

# only check if var is unset
echo ${var+literal_out_put}

if [[ -z ${var+literal_out_put} ]];
then 
    echo var is unset;
else
    echo var = $var
fi
```

Output:

```
abc
literal_out_put
var =
```

Table from https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

[image]

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: @Shawn Thanks. I checked some similar ref before. But it only talks about `:+`. Not `+`.

Comment: Ah, I found the explanation.  *the \<colon\> in the format shall result in a test for a parameter that is unset or null; omission of the \<colon\> shall result in a test for a parameter that is only unset.* -- from https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02